# Can a positive operator acting on $C_{b}(X)$ be extended to a positive operator acting on $C(\beta X)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normal or completely regular topological space, $C_{b}(X)$ the set of all real bounded continuous functions on $X$ and $T:C_{b}(X)\to C_{b}(X)$ a positive linear operator. I would like to know wether $T$ can be extended to a positive linear operator $\bar{T}:C(\beta X) \to C(\beta X)$, where $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.

Comment: Positive under what inner product?

Comment: @PaulSinclair here positivity is understood in the Banach lattice sense, i.e., $Tf\geq 0$ whenever $f\geq 0$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extend"...$C_b(X)$ and $C(\beta X)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @EricWofsey I knew this isomorphism in locally compact case, but for completely regular is new for me. Can you explain how to obtain this result or provide a reference ?

Comment: Local compactness is totally irrelevant; any proof of this fact for locally compact spaces should work just as well for any space.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely trivial, since $C_b(X)$ and $C(\beta X)$ are the same thing so there's no "extending" to do at all.  More precisely, the map $r:C(\beta X)\to C_b(X)$ taking a function on $\beta X$ to its restriction to $X$ is an isomorphism (of Banach lattices, or of pretty much any natural structure you might care about).  The fact that $r$ is a bijection is immediate from the definition of $\beta X$ (by definition, every bounded continuous function on $X$ extends uniquely to $\beta X$).  Clearly $r$ is linear, and the fact that it preserves the norm and the order follows from the fact that $X$ is dense in $\beta X$ and so if $f\in C(\beta X)$, the image of $f$ is just the closure of the image of the restriction $r(f)$.

(Note that none of this even requires $X$ to be completely regular; you just have to interpret "restrict from $\beta X$ to $X$" to mean "compose with the canonical map $X\to\beta X$", since that map may not be injective.)

Answer (score 1):

If we also assume that $X$ is Hausdorff, then we can consider $X \subseteq \beta X$. Define $$\overline T : C(\beta X) \to C(\beta X): f \mapsto \beta(Tf|_X)$$

Linearity of $\overline T$ follows from the universality of $\beta$: $a\overline T(f) + b\overline T(g)$ is an extension of $T((af + bg)|_X) = aT(f|_X) + bT(g|_X)$ to all of $\beta X$, and thus must be the unique extension $\beta(T(af + bg)|_X) = \overline T(af + bg)$.

And if $f \ge 0$, then $T(f|_X) \ge 0$ by the positivity of $T$. Hence $ T(f|_X) \subseteq [0, b]$ for some $b$, and so $\overline T(f) = \beta T(f|_X) \subseteq [0, b]$ as well (by definition, the $\beta$ lifting does not change the compact codomain of the function). Thus $\overline T(f) \ge 0$.

If we don't have that $X$ is Hausdorff, then I'm not sure that it holds.